# Meaning of ! in Java syntax

Tags: java, syntax

In the line below where it shows `return(!variable);` what does the exclamation mark do to the variable?

```
return(!weekday || vacation);
```

Comment: Apart from the answers you'll probably find this useful too: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: I don't see why this gets downvoted. For a newbie, this IS hard to search on Google.

Comment: +1 to counteract the minus. I dont see anything wrong with the question.

Comment: The only thing wrong is that the title could use some work so it's more relevant to the question. But I don't know the best way to phrase it, or I would edit it.

Comment: If you have further questions about Java operators, look here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html (found by Googling "Java operators")

Comment: The problem is not so much the question but the implication: People start programming completely clueless, they don't even bother reading the introduction to the basics of the language.  Please read it before proceeding. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `!` is a boolean NOT operator, defined in [Section 15.15.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.15.6) of the Java Language Specification. It makes `true` `false` and `false` `true`. So what that return statement is doing is returning a boolean which will be `true` if *either* `weekday` is `false` ("not weekday") or (`||`) `vacation` is `true`. It will be `false` if `weekday` is `true`and `vacation` is `false`.

Answer (score 11):

The `!` character is logical negation. It's formal name is, I believe, "logical not". Logically, `!true == false` and `!false == true`.

Like Platinum Azure said in the comments, this operator can only be applied to `boolean` types.

Comment: Specifically logical negation-- that is, if given a `true` value it will return `false`, and if given a `false` value it will return `true`. Java does not allow use of the `!` operator on non-`boolean` types.

Comment: Logical Complement Operator (Java Language Specification 15.15.6) It is applicable on `boolean` AND `Boolean` types!

Comment: @Carlos With autoboxing and autounboxing, you can apply a lot of operators to both the primitive and object types. For example, `+` can be applied to `Integer` just like `integer`. But that's a whole different discussion.

Comment: I (and the authors of the JLS) do not think so. Autounboxing of `Boolean` is part of the execution of `!`

Answer (score 5):

`!` means negation. Basically, "Ok, so whatever follows, if it is true, return false, if false return true." (`!` will only work on booleans in Java) In this case, your return becomes:

> return that it is not a weekday or that it is vacation.

Answer (score 1):

It means when `NOT weekday` (boolean false). `!` stands for negation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a negation. `!` means `not`.